# $\lim_{x \to 0,y\to 0} \frac{\ (x\tan y+4)^\frac12-2}{y \sin x}=?$

Tags: limits

I have a question:

$$\lim_{x \to 0,y\to 0} \frac{\ (x\tan y+4)^\frac12-2}{y \sin x}=?$$

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Where is $y$?${}$

Comment: Sorry. Now it is right.

Comment: Use $(1+x)^n-1\sim nx$ when $x\rightarrow0$

Comment: Is there a simple method to solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$(x\tan y+4)^{\frac12}=2\left(1+\frac{x\tan y}{4}\right)^{\frac12}\sim2\left(1+\frac{x\tan y}{8}\right)$$
so
$$ \frac{\ (x\tan y+4)^\frac12-2}{y \sin x}\sim\frac14\frac{x}{\sin x}\frac{\tan y}{y}\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac14$$